# Allows editing UIImagePickerViewController doesn't work picking 2 different images

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view with 2 `UIImageViews` and 2 buttons in order to select 2 different pictures with `UIImagePickerViewController`. It actually works perfect but I would like to zoom the images and finally show the selected part of the image in the `UIImageViews`.

Allows editing works correctly with zoom and it apparently ''allows to edit' the pictures, but in the end the selected part is not presented in the UIImageViews .

Code is here. What is wrong?

```
import UIKit

var fotoUnoEscogida = UIImage()
var fotoDosEscogida = UIImage()


class viewControllerDso : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate{


    //Images
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!
    //TextViews
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewExteriorUno: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewExteriorDos: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewInteriorUno: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewInteriorDos: UITextView!




    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var imagePicked = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    }


    @IBAction func chooseImage(sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
            print("chooseImage Button capture ")

            imagePicked = sender.tag
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        if imagePicked == 1 {

            imageView1.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            imageView1.image = pickedImage

            imageView1.layer.masksToBounds = true
            imageView1.layer.borderWidth = 6
            imageView1.layer.cornerRadius = imageView1.layer.frame.height/6
            imageView1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2).CGColor




        } else if imagePicked == 2 {


            imageView2.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            imageView2.image = pickedImage

            imageView2.layer.masksToBounds = true
            imageView2.layer.borderWidth = 6
            imageView2.layer.cornerRadius = imageView2.layer.frame.height/6
            imageView2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2).CGColor




        }
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`
instead of

```
let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

use

```
let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Swift 5.2

```
let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage]
```